# Creating a new column of 'ID's' from a condition

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, assign

I am a novice when it comes to R and have run in to quite a specific issue that I can't seem to find much help with online. It also doesn't help that asking questions in stack overflow doesn't seem that straightforward. So please bare with me.

To provide some context this is an incredibly large dataset, 250,000  records plus with 9 columns.

One of these columns is called 'Site_ID'.

I now have a huge dataset that is sorted by Site_ID and date. The issue that I have is that a Site ID often does not correspond to just one set of coordinates and what I want is to create a new column that gives a new Site ID when the location changes. As the GPS coordinates have a large amount of error associated with them, the only way to separate them is by essentially 'flagging' when a Site ID is 'deployed' and assigning the same Site ID to all the following records, until the next deploy occurs and then beginning that process again.

In pseudocode  it would be something like....

NewColumn <- ifelse(Task_Type == "Deploy trap", assign int val, assign previous rows int val)

The expected output would be a new column that has a series of new site ID's in descending order from 1:n (n = however many Deploys there are in the dataset)

Please let me know if I can provide anymore, I have snapshots of data available, I am simply unsure of how to use the stackoverflow Ask a Question page effectively.

```
TRIALDATA$SITEIDDEPLOY = ifelse(TRIALDATA$Task_Type == 'Deploy trap', paste0(TRIALDATA$Site_ID, "_1"), TRIALDATA$Site_ID)
```

This code sample is what I used previously to achieve the data in the attached image. [image: Output1]

structure(list(Longitude = c(1414394, 1414394, 1414398, 1411206,
1411206, 1411206, 1411206, 1412729, 1412729, 1412729, 1412733,
1414625, 1414625, 1414623, 1414456, 1414456, 1414456, 1414456,
1414456, 1414456, 1414455, 1411308, 1411308, 1411308, 1411307,
1411215, 1411215, 1411215, 1411214, 1414286, 1414286, 1414286,
1414286, 1414292, 1409923, 1409923, 1409923, 1409923, 1409923,
1409920), Latitude = c(4925150, 4925150, 4925147, 4921828, 4921828,
4921828, 4921827, 4923623, 4923623, 4923623, 4923620, 4925285,
4925285, 4925288, 4923812, 4923812, 4923812, 4923812, 4923812,
4923812, 4923802, 4922003, 4922003, 4922003, 4922002, 4921976,
4921976, 4921976, 4921974, 4924632, 4924632, 4924632, 4924632,
4924636, 4920300, 4920300, 4920300, 4920300, 4920300, 4920300
), Site_ID = c("100000060049", "100000060049", "100000060049",
"100000060070", "100000060070", "100000060070", "100000060070",
"100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155",
"100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155",
"100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155",
"100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155",
"100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060179", "100000060179",
"100000060179", "100000060179", "100000060209", "100000060209",
"100000060209", "100000060209", "100000060209", "100000060209",
"100000060209", "100000060209", "100000060209", "100000060209",
"100000060209"), Task_Type = c("Deploy trap", "Check trap", "Remove trap",
"Deploy trap", "Check trap", "Check trap", "Remove trap", "Deploy trap",
"Check trap", "Check trap", "Remove trap", "Deploy trap", "Check trap",
"Remove trap", "Deploy trap", "Check trap", "Check trap", "Check trap",
"Check trap", "Check trap", "Remove trap", "Deploy trap", "Check trap",
"Check trap", "Remove trap", "Deploy trap", "Check trap", "Check trap",
"Remove trap", "Deploy trap", "Check trap", "Check trap", "Check trap",
"Remove trap", "Deploy trap", "Check trap", "Check trap", "Check trap",
"Check trap", "Remove trap"), Task_Option = c("Leg-hold - possum",
"Still set", "Still set", "Leg-hold - possum", "Still set", "Still set",
"Still set", "Leg-hold - possum", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set",
"Leg-hold - possum", "Still set", "Still set", "Leg-hold - possum",
"Still set", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set",
"Still set", "Leg-hold - possum", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set",
"Leg-hold - possum", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set", "Leg-hold - possum",
"Still set", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set", "Leg-hold - possum",
"Still set", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set", "Still set"
), Additional_Data = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,
NA_character_, NA_character_), Time = c("11:32:41", "13:54:16",
"12:35:40", "09:23:50", "15:10:06", "14:44:31", "08:10:30", "11:33:14",
"14:53:36", "15:05:08", "12:46:37", "09:39:50", "13:54:17", "11:43:09",
"09:07:30", "14:32:55", "15:08:07", "16:05:35", "13:37:02", "14:50:06",
"08:57:05", "08:25:12", "15:10:07", "14:44:31", "08:03:35", "08:30:32",
"15:10:06", "14:44:31", "08:06:16", "12:59:51", "16:05:33", "13:37:05",
"12:36:12", "11:47:09", "14:24:09", "15:05:23", "12:58:22", "09:36:56",
"14:13:32", "08:08:02"), Date = structure(c(1516060800, 1516147200,
1516233600, 1517875200, 1517961600, 1518048000, 1518134400, 1515542400,
1515628800, 1515715200, 1515801600, 1516060800, 1516147200, 1516233600,
1516579200, 1516665600, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517011200,
1517097600, 1517875200, 1517961600, 1518048000, 1518134400, 1517875200,
1517961600, 1518048000, 1518134400, 1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800,
1517011200, 1517097600, 1518048000, 1518134400, 1518220800, 1518307200,
1518393600, 1518480000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt")), SITEIDDEPLOY = c("100000060049_1", "100000060049",
"100000060049", "100000060070_1", "100000060070", "100000060070",
"100000060070", "100000060155_1", "100000060155", "100000060155",
"100000060155", "100000060155_1", "100000060155", "100000060155",
"100000060155_1", "100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155",
"100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155_1",
"100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060155", "100000060179_1",
"100000060179", "100000060179", "100000060179", "100000060209_1",
"100000060209", "100000060209", "100000060209", "100000060209",
"100000060209_1", "100000060209", "100000060209", "100000060209",
"100000060209", "100000060209")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: It is easier to help if you provide data in a reproducible format and not as an image. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). If your data is very big, you can share a small subset using `dput(head(df, 10))` where `df` is your dataframe name. Remove the columns which are not necessary for the question. You can also create a fake dataset which is similar to your original dataset if you have sensitive information. Don't forget to share the expected output for the data shared so that we can verify our answers while posting them.

Comment: Great, thankyou for the pointers, will sort it now

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Ronak, when you say expected output do you mean what the desired out come would be? If I am understanding correctly, a column of integers. For example, in the image shown, a new column next to SITEIDDEPLOY. For example, the first 3 records would have a value of 1, the next 4 records would have a value of 2. Essentially any time a 'deploy trap' record is reached a new value is created as the output and applied to all records until the next 'Deploy trap' record is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` here -

```
TRIALDATA$result <- cumsum(TRIALDATA$Task_Type == "Deploy trap")
```

The counts are saved in new column `result`. This will increment the count every time `Task_Type = "Deploy trap"`.